# DSA optimisation problem from n^3 to n^2 time

Tags: javascript, optimization, data-structures, integer

The problem statement says given a positive integer "N" we have to find combination of four positive integers which add up to that number. Then print all the possible combinations. I was given the 3 sum version of this which I solved using 3 loops (N^3) then I optimized it for (N^2) then I was asked to do 4 sum that I was able to do in (N^3) as well but I was also asked to optimize it for N^2 but I am unable to do that. Any suggestions how I might be able to do that?

The input is just an integer and we have to find combination of 4 integers from 1 to N that add up to N.

My N^3 code:

```JavaScript
let N = 5;

for (let I = 1; I <= N - 3; I++) {
  for (let J = 1; J <= N - 3; J++) {
    for (let K = 1; K <= N - 3; K+) {
      let L = L - (I + J + K);
      if (L >= 1)
        console.log(I, J, K, L)
    }
  }
}
```

> Output will be
> 1 1 1 2,
> 1 1 2 1,
> 1 2 1 1,
> 2 1 1 1

Comment: It is customary to post your code (just paste it, select, and hit ctrl-k to format it) instead of a picture/link....  Easier for those helping out to work with it.  That said, you could certainly tighten up the loops you have now, right?  the upper limit on the loop for `i` is good right now, but how about `j`?  don't you have some information about `i` that you could use to reduce that loop?  Similarly for `k`?

Comment: You have to *print* all the combinations? There are too many combinations. You can't print O(N^3) things in O(N^2) time.